# Save one line of echo to variable in BASH?

Tags: linux, bash, echo

Okay the answer to this may be really simple but I have been searching for a while and I can't figure it out. I have a variable called "tmessagef". The variable is formatted like:

```
value1*value2*vlaue3*value4*value5
```

The only part of the variable I want is value 5. I am currently using the following code but it only prints each value and doesn't save them to a variable:

```
OIFS=$IFS
IFS='*'
arr2=$tmessagef
for x in $arr2
do
    echo "$x"
done
IFS=$OIFS
```

What I want to do is get the 5th line that the echo command produces and save that to a variable called "tmessage". How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: change 'echo' to 'tmessage ='

Comment: @Rohan What do you mean?

Comment: Change `echo "$x"` to `val="$x"`. At the end of the loop `$val` will contain the last value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe mcalex's comment should answer it:

> Change `echo "$x"` to `tmessage="$x"`. At the end of the loop $val will contain the last value

Comment: i reckon mcalex got there first

Answer (score 1):

Array manipulation:

```
OIFS="$IFS" IFS='*' Y=($X)
x=${Y[${#Y[@]}-1]}
IFS="$OIFS"
```

Comment: Because your test values don't contain e.g. `[0-9]` with a file named `5` in the current directory. wordsplitting with IFS should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

For this very specific scenario (where you only want to extract the value at the very end), you can use parameter expansion

```
echo "${word##*\*}"
```

or assign it to a variable instead of using "echo".

**Explanation**:

- `##` removes the longest substring anchored at the beginning that matches the pattern
- `*` matches any number of any character
- `\*` matches a literal asterisk

So basically, remove the longest substring that ends with an asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use cut?

```
VAL=`echo 'value1*value2*vlaue3*value4*value5' | cut -f5 -d'*'`
```

Comment: yes cut is not bash, but you can often achieve what you need by combining simple tools that are already provided. Yup $VAL= should be VAL=, edited.

Comment: this is the most straightforward answer, if we fix the syntax. In bash, we can write `val=$(cut -d\* -f5 <<< "$line")
`

Answer (score 0):

```
IFS=* read -r _{,,,} tmessage _ <<<"$tmessagef"
```

or

```
[[ $tmessagef =~ ^(.*\*){4}(.*)\* ]]; tmessage=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
```

Read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 and the trillion other answers to this question.

Don't use echo for this. If you have output that needs saving, see: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002